# нужна помощь с классами в C#

Tags: c#, строки, классы, переменные

```
using System;

namespace t
{
    class Program
    {
            public class students
            {
                public int age;

                public students(int age)
                {
                    this.age = age;
                }
            }

            public static void Main()
            {
                string peremenay = "Bitaly";

                students Bitaly = new students(33);

                //этот вариант мне не подходит
                Console.WriteLine(Bitaly.age);
                //можно ли сделать так чтоб вместо слова Bitaly была переменная string со значением Bitaly


            //этот вариант не работает
            //Console.WriteLine(peremenay.age);
            

            Console.ReadKey();
            }
        }
    }
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

В вашем примере логичнее всего хранить имя в [поле](https://docs.microsoft.com/ru-ru/dotnet/csharp/programming-guide/classes-and-structs/fields) класса:

```
class Student
{
    public string Name;
}

...

var Vitaly = new Student { Name = "Vitaly" };
var name = Vitaly.Name;

Console.WriteLine(name);
```

Получить имя переменной можно с помощью `nameof()`:

```
var Vitaly = new Student();
var name = nameof(Vitaly);

Console.WriteLine(name); // Vitaly
```

Получить имя класса по его [экземпляру](https://docs.microsoft.com/ru-ru/dotnet/csharp/programming-guide/classes-and-structs/objects):

```
var Vitaly = new Student();
var type = Vitaly.GetType().Name;

Console.WriteLine(type); // Student
```